# Update: Matrix-Diagonal Multiplication Proof Verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Define the following:

- $\mathbf{T}\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ an $n\times n$ matrix.
- $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$ a column vector.
- $\Psi=\operatorname{diag}(c)$ outputs an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix.

I am asked to show when I multiply $\mathbf{\Psi}\mathbf{T}$, I am essentially multiplying each row $i$ of $\mathbf{T}$ by $c_{i}$.

---

I proceed to show this as follow:

A matrix-matrix multiplication is defined by the following mathematical operation:
$$
\mathbf{AB}=\left[\sum_{{k=1}}^{n}\mathbf{A}(i,k)\mathbf{B}(k,j)\right]_{i,j}=\left[\sum_{{k=1}}^{n}a_{i,k}b_{k,j}\right]_{i,j}
$$
Our case, the matrix $\mathbf{\Psi}\mathbf{T}$ is non-zero whenever $i=k$ this means that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{\Psi T}&=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbf{\Psi}(i,k)\mathbf{T}(k,j)\right]_{i,j}\\\\
&=\left[\mathbf{\Psi}(i,i)\mathbf{T}(i,j)\right]_{i,j}\\\\
&=\left[\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{c})(i,i)\mathbf{T}(i,j)\right]_{i,j}\\\\
&=c_{i}\mathbf{T}(i,:)
\end{align*}
where $1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n$.
I am unsure if I solved it correctly or not.

**[Note]**: I may need to state that $\mathbf{T}(i,:)$ is MATLAB's way of looping over the columns of $\mathbf{T}$ for a fixed row $i$.

**[Update]**: I have taken @0XLR remarks into account and have update my derivation. I hope someone confirms if this is a complete proof.

Comment: Your notation is bad: $\sum_{\underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{k=1}}}^{n}A(i,k)B(k,j)$ makes it seem like you are summing over $i$ and $j$ also. You should use something like $\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{n}A(i,k)B(k,j)\Big]_{i,j}$ which is much clearer. In fact, you got confused by your own notation. The second line in your derivation should not be summing over $i$. It should be $\Big[\text{diag}(c)(i,i)\mathbf{T}(i, j)\Big]_{i, j}$ and of course $\text{diag}(c)(i,i) = c_i$.

Comment: You are correct @0XLR I did have this inner feeling that I was abusing notation I think because of this I did not reach the correct conclusion. Apart from that would my answer be correct after fixing this notation problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\D#1{{\rm Diag}\left(#1\right)}\def\e{\varepsilon}$Suppose
you have two vectors and their corresponding diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A = \D{a}\qquad B = \D{b} \\
}$$
The product of these diagonal matrices with an arbitrary matrix
$X\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times m}$ is equivalent to the Hadamard product
of the matrix with the two vectors
$$AXB = ab^T\odot X$$
Since the matrix can be written as a sum of its columns $\{c_i\}$ or rows $\{r_j^T\}$ multiplied by the cartesian basis vectors, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X &= \sum_{i=1}^m c_i\e_i^T = \sum_{j=1}^n e_jr_j^T \\
}$$
Therefore the product with the diagonal matrices can be expanded as
$$\eqalign{
AXB
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m ab^T\odot c_i\e_i^T 
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m (a\odot c_i)(b\odot\e_i)^T \\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^n ab^T\odot e_jr_j^T 
 &= \sum_{j=1}^n (a\odot e_j)(b\odot r_j)^T \\
}$$
So, as you suspected, the columns get multiplied (*element-wise*) by $a$ and the rows by $b$.

In your particular problem $\;\,B=I,\;b={\tt1},\;(b\odot\e_i)=\e_i$